# how to spilt new line without changing the index

Tags: java

I want to draw a 6*6 grid like this:

```
~~~~~~
~~~~~~
~~~~~~
~~~~~~
~~~~~~
~~~~~~
```

using (x, y) to represent each one of them and then I can modify them using 5y+x+1, so im now using :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("~~~~~~" +
'\n' + "~~~~~~"+
'\n' + "~~~~~~"+
'\n' + "~~~~~~"+
'\n' + "~~~~~~"+
'\n' + "~~~~~~");
```

this method to draw the grid, but now the '\n' took the index 6, 14, 21, 28. 
The order is different, what can i do to draw this grid and split the line without changing the index of the original grid?

Comment: How about using two `for-loops` to achieve the same?

Comment: There's no use of using the `StringBuffer` if you are using concatenation of strings. Just use `String sb = ...`

Comment: `\n` is the line breaker, you need it, and when printing `sb` you won't see the `\n` so your desiered output is met. I'm not sure what you are asking. Check the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZsMx.png).

Answer (score 1):

Change the grid to 6*7. Store the line separator in the last column. You can still use a similar formula to change the cells:

```
(x,y) -> 7y + x
```